# Extend Boot and EFI Partitions CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos7, partition, boot

I got a new dedicated server which have 500GB SSD holding the operating system and the other HDDs have the data. By default the `/boot` partition is considered small I wanna extend it same applies to `EFI` as shown below:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                  32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     32G  9.4M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs                     32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cl-root      402G  8.1G  394G   3% /
/dev/sda2               1014M  172M  843M  17% /boot
/dev/sda1                200M   12M  189M   6% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0               3.9G  8.4M  3.7G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                    6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0
```

I'm trying to extend `/boot` and `EFI` partitions using `resize2fs` but the system isn't allowing me and I don't wanna create an `LVM` for them. I have 20GB free with LVM which I'm trying to unallocate from LVM as a free space then I can use `fdisk` to delete boot partitions and re-create them with the new space.

Any help how to unallocate the LVM free space and use them for fdisk? Or other solutions of expanding /boot.

Map of Physical Drive `/dev/sda`

```
[root@example ~]# fdisk -l /dev/sda
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 499.6 GB, 499558383616 bytes, 975699968 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2B62023B-35F9-4A40-B259-B0088B5FA7A8

#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648      2508799      1G  Microsoft basic
 3      2508800    975697919  464.1G  Linux LVM
```

Thank you!

Comment: By which criteria is an almost `1 GiB` `/boot` partition small? If you want to move partitions you need to provide their physical position on the hard drive: `fdisk -l /dev/sda`.

Comment: is 1GB enough for boot what about updates will fill the partition which requires manual actions?

Comment: The `/boot` partition basically contains pairs of kernel (about `5 MiB`) and initial RAM disk (about `50 MiB`) and some bootloader configuration. You need around 20 kernels to fill it. New distributions automatically delete old kernels on upgrade.

Comment: We are still waiting for a map of your physical partitions: `fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thank you I've added the map to the question.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the size of the `/boot` partition you need access to a rescue mode: i.e. your server can not boot from the hard drive. Once you have that, you can:

1. Shrink the physical volume `/dev/sda3` as much as you can. E.g.:

   ```
   pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 400G /dev/sda3
   ```
2. Shrink the physical partition, i.e. delete it and create a new one. You must take care to leave the starting sector (`2508800`) the same and at least `400G` on the partition. Leave enough space at the end of the disk for another partition.
3. Resize the physical volume `/dev/sda3` to fill the new partition:

   ```
   pvresize /dev/sda3
   ```
4. Create a new partition (`/dev/sda4` for example), format it and copy the files from `/dev/sda2`.
5. Update your bootloader to use the new partition.

**Warning**: moving partitions can **break** your system for what I believe is little to no gain: you will never really need more than a . Different tools can use different units: e.g. some use [mebibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte), while some use [megabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte). With some effort, you might also be able to move the beginning of `/dev/sda3` further away to make more space for `/dev/sda2`.